# Image won't stay inside div border

Tags: css, wordpress, html

**Website:** [isfnpub.com](http://isfnpub.com)

Right now I'm using extra padding to get the image to fit, but as you see, the div thing is completely ignoring the image.

I'm working inside Wordpress.

Code used:

```
<div style="border: 5px solid #FFC85D; padding: 10px; margin:30px;">

<p><strong>UPCOMING RELEASE: ISFN ANTHOLOGY #1</strong></p>

<p>[caption id="attachment_801" align="alignright" 
width="189" 
caption="Click image for full cover spread."]
<a href="http://ISFNpub.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/cover-small-full.jpg" 
target="_blank">
<img src="http://ISFNpub.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/cover-small-189x300.jpg" 
alt="" 
title="Anthology 1 front" 
width="189" height="300" 
class="size-medium wp-image-801" /></a>
[/caption]
<strong>Authors: </strong> blah blah blah.</p>

<p><strong>Cover Art By:</strong> Xenia Latii</p>

<p>blah blah blah</p>

</div>
```

I want the div border to naturally wrap around all of the content, including the image.  Without the extra padding the image overlaps the border and everything looks uglo.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I used `<div style="overflow:auto; ...">` and it seems to work. Is this an appropriate solution, or will I run into trouble later on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'used "'.  Please clarify.

Comment: It was a typo. "I used '<div style="overflow:auto; ...">'"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly then I think that's what you need.
Try to use `overflow:hidden` that should be solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try `overflow: hidden` and set the width of the div to say for example 300px then set the pictures width to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

you need set width and height for your img tag in div:

e.g.

img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" alt="abc..." src="https://somesite/your_pic.png"

Answer (score -2):

Both the overflow options suggested just cut off the part of the image that is outside of the div, rather than getting the image to resize to fit within, which is what really needs to happen. I found that using the div properties `float-none` seems to do the trick.